# Image is not appearing when JLabel is clicked from JButton menu (java)

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, embedded-resource

My question is about Image not appearing when jlabel is clicked from menu
Why does the image does not appear when I click from menu? Please help. Newbie here

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Lab05Part02 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JMenuItem b1,b2,b3;
JLabel bankImg;
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("aib.jpg");
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("BOI.jpg");
ImageIcon img3 = new ImageIcon("kbc.jpeg");

Lab05Part02(){

    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu banks = new JMenu("Banks", false);

    banks.add(b1 = new JMenuItem("AIB"));
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    banks.add(b2 = new JMenuItem("Bank of Ireland"));
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    banks.add(b3 = new JMenuItem("KBC"));
    b3.addActionListener(this);

    mb.add(banks);
    setJMenuBar(mb);

    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    bankImg = new JLabel();

    p.add(bankImg);
    getContentPane().add(p);

    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);


}//end of constructor

public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab05Part02 myMenu = new Lab05Part02();


}//end of main method

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    Object source = new Object();

    if(source == b1){

         bankImg.setIcon(img1);

    }
    else if(source == b2){

        bankImg.setIcon(img2);

    }
    else if(source == b3){

        bankImg.setIcon(img3);

    }

    else{

        bankImg.setText("Select Image from Menu");

    }


}//end of listener method

}//end of class
```

Where did I go wrong? On else if statements? Can someone explain this to me? I did putting setVisible(true) on every condition but it did not work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `actionPerformed` method you forgot to get the source object from the `ActionEvent e` and you just created a new object:

```
Object source = new Object();
```

As it's obvious, in this way `source` is not equals to the reference of one of your buttons.

The `ActionEvent` object contains the source of event. In order to resolve the issue get the source object from `ActionEvent e` argument:

```
Object source = e.getSource();
```

If your images ("aib.jpg", "BOI.jpg" and "kbc.jpeg") are in a right path and your `ImageIcon img1, img2, img3` objects populated successfully you are good to go with the above fix.

But I can advise that if you want no further inconvenience for showing images and icons in your project, it's better you put them under a package like `resources.images` and also create a java class there and name it `Resources.java` for example.

Then you can create images using the resource stream of `Resources.java` which is in the same package with images and icons:

```
package resources.images;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Resources {
    public static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String name) {
        URL imagePath = Resources.class.getResource(name);
        return new ImageIcon(imagePath);
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can write

```
ImageIcon img1 = Resources.getImageIcon("aib.jpg");
```

instead of

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("aib.jpg");
```

This way it will work even if you package your application as a jar file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you have suggestions where I can find java tutorials as a beginner? Thanks in advance

Comment: @LyraOpena: There are so many free and commercial java tutorials available on the web one of which is: https://www.udemy.com/java-tutorial/ but you can find so much more by googling to fit with your level of expertise